# Enable Chromium / Dartium within Dart plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dart, dart-editor, dart-eclipse-plugin

I installed the dart plugin and put the dartium (freshly downloaded) in the eclipse project. The folder is called chromium.

When I now start the project nothing happens. Dart plugin has a property in the preferences where I can specifiy the location of a custom browser to start. Does anyone know what I should select here or what I missed.

Answer (score 4):

'dartium' must be in a directory called 'chromium' at the root of your eclipse installation.

For example, if your eclipse is at ~/dev/java/eclipse and you have unzipped dartium to ~/downloads/google/dartium-lucid64-full-stable-1.12.1.0 then if you symbolicaly link

ln -s ~/downloads/google/dartium-lucid64-full-stable-1.12.1.0 ~/dev/java/eclipse/chromium

then the eclipse dart plugin will find dartium.

Comment: format it a little, so that your gist answer could catch the viewers eye at first sight.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, I place my Chromium.app package in a "chromium" directory that is a child of the actual eclipse install directory.

(e.g. /Applications/eclipse-4.3.2/chromium/Chromium.app)

[image]

Comment: Thats what I did but I failed. I use Eclipse 3.8 so I might be using an incompatible platform, but it does not complain about anything

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  If I get some time soon, I'll try it on 3.8 just to see if there is some discrepancy.